# Hiding multiple rows based on cell values

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have an algorithm that works fine to hide all rows where, in a specified named range, a given row has the value 0. It's straightforward enough:

```
Public Sub MasquerLignesAZeroRapport(rap As Worksheet)
    Dim cell As Range
    rap.Rows.Hidden = False

    For Each cell In rap.Range("Ra_LignesAZero")
        If Round(cell.Value, 0) = 0 Then
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

This, however, takes a bit of time even when calculation and screen updating are turned off and I have tried different other methods without success (using a filter and hiding all visible rows but removing the filter unhides the rows, the same goes for setting the row height to 0).

Is there a faster alternative ? I can live with that slow algorithm but it would be a welcome improvement as this macro may be run against 1-6 reports in a single run.

Comment: Consider using an autofilter

Comment: I presume the `Ra_LignesAZero` range only has 1 column?

Comment: Yes. Also this may be a blonde moment but indeed I can use an auto filter.  It just doesn't seem as clean. Maybe I am over thinking this.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few optimizations:

```
Public Sub MasquerLignesAZeroRapport(rap As Worksheet)
'Optimization #1: as you pointed out, turning off calculations
' and screen updating makes a difference.
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    rap.Rows.Hidden = False

    'Optimization #2: instead of loading each cell as a range,
    ' with all the associated properties, load JUST the values
    ' into a 2 dimensional array.
    Dim values() As Variant
    values = rap.Range("Ra_LignesAZero")  

    For r = 1 To UBound(values, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(values, 2)
            If Round(values(r,c), 0) = 0 Then
                rap.Rows(r).Hidden = True
                'Optimization #3: if we have already determined
                ' that the row should be hidden, no need to keep
                ' looking at cells in the row - might as well break out of the For:
                Exit For 
            End If
        Next
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```